# Meteor + MongoDB Iterative processing

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor, and I want to get a list of contacts:
- each contacts has an id, 
- I want to search the DB for all the user to see if I find matching IDs, 
- if I find them I need to: a) update my contact[i] b) update the found ID with my personal ID

The problem with this is that I don't manage [so far] to do this operation with Mongo.

Full post is here https://forums.meteor.com/t/connecting-users-mongo-strategy/4132

Code here:

```
for (var i = 0;i < contacts.length; i++) {
            Meteor.users.find({"profile.phone": contacts[i].phone}).forEach(function(friend){
                console.log('We found a friend', friend);
                contacts[i].appActive = true;
                contacts[i].appId = friend._id;

                Meteor.users.update({_id: friend._id}, { $addToSet: { "profile.friends": Meteor.userId() }});
            });
        }
```

The logic is sound, the problem is with HOW I understand Mongo [poorly], I'm guessing the queries are async, I'm trying to create a cursor with find on the server side but I'm stuck.

Any pointer are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post all relevant codes and resources in the **question itself**. If for some reason the Meteor website dies (or is deviated by a larger mass), your question will lack critical data. Here, we need two things: Your code and your document structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to limit your database calls.  If I understand your use, you need one call to fetch friend records and a second call to update all those records with the current userId.

The db calls within the loop over `contacts` can be avoided by creating separate array of phone numbers.

```
var phones = _.pluck(contacts, 'phone');
Meteor.users.find({'profile.phone':{$in: phones}}).forEach( function (friend) {
  var ii = phones.indexOf( friend.profile.phone );
  contacts[ii].appActive = true;
  contacts[ii].appId = friend._id;
});

Meteor.users.update(
  {'profile.phone':{$in: phones}}, 
  {$addToSet: {'profile.friends': Meteor.userId()}},
  {multi: true}  // all matching records receive update
);
```

Comment: Yeah, the logic was mostly sound, but your input here is even better. The problem I had [of course] was that I used to process and hash the phone numbers, I processed them ONLY for the contacts array, not the user's actual phone (facepalm), took me a while to get that, I got the crazy idea to start comparing the hashesm then I found that dumb TYPO. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not look too bad in my opinion. (as long as it's server side) And no, in Meteor, most collection methods are not asynchronous! Just use [Collection.findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) and it should work:

```
for (var i = 0;i < contacts.length; i++) {
           var friend = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.phone": contacts[i].phone});
                console.log('We found a friend', friend);
                contacts[i].appActive = true;
                contacts[i].appId = friend._id;

                Meteor.users.update({_id: friend._id}, { $addToSet: { "profile.friends": Meteor.userId() }});
        }
```

If you **do** want to get multiple users with the same phone number (I thought it was weird, so I assumed phone numbers were unique), you will need to use `find().fetch()` before your `forEach`:

```
for (var i = 0;i < contacts.length; i++) {
            Meteor.users.find({"profile.phone": contacts[i].phone}).fetch().forEach(function(friend){
                console.log('We found a friend', friend);
                contacts[i].appActive = true;
                contacts[i].appId = friend._id;

                Meteor.users.update({_id: friend._id}, { $addToSet: { "profile.friends": Meteor.userId() }});
            });
        }
```

If for some reason you want to do this client-side, you will first need to [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) your users on server side, and [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) to your publication on client side. Here's [a nice article about it](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) from Discover Meteor.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the code is server side in a method. I found my problem, commented in the above answer.